# O que levou a criação do Programmers.se?

Tags: debate

Na língua inglesa, além do StackOverflow, há também uma comunidade chamada [***Programmers***](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Conforme o [help desta comunidade](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) há tópicos que lhe são pertinentes, porém outros devem ser tratados no [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). O que levou tal divisão?

Optei em fazer esta pergunta em português aqui para compreender melhor a política do SE em geral e evitar mal entendidos devido ao idioma.

Comment: Pode ajudar: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/

Comment: O segundo link me respondeu bem a pergunta: "In a nutshell, Stack Overflow is for when you’re front of your compiler or editor working through code issues. Programmers is for when you’re in front of a whiteboard working through higher level conceptual programming issues. Hence the (awesome) whiteboard inspired design!"

Comment: @bfavaretto era bom uma resposta em Português.

Comment: Eu não acompanhei a criação do Programmers, mas o que ouvi dizer é que ele começou de um jeito (aceitando perguntas de interesse de programadores, mas não sobre programação) e depois mudou para o escopo atual. Também já vi gente questionando se hoje em dia essa divisão ainda faz algum sentido.

Comment: O @bigown foi moderador do Programmers, se não me engano. Acho que ele poderá ajudar.